# Character count python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I do this to count the characters on the strings but in the end not really sure how to count all the characters in all of the strings together!

import sys

```
def main ():
    nr = 1
    for line in sys.stdin :
        line = line.rstrip ()
        print (len(line))
        nr = nr + 1

main()
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: it gives me the length of the lines, once I get it. I don't know how I could get the sum of the length of all the lines.

Answer (score 1):

For counting total characters in all string you can use this:

```
import sys
count = 0

def main ():
    global count
    for line in sys.stdin :
        line = line.rstrip ()
        print (len(line))
        count += len(line)  #same as count=count+len(line)
    return count

print("total characters : "+str(main()))
```